# Create Person(Real person or Legal Person) using design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have person class :

```
public class Person : 
    {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public Guid? PersonRealId { get; set; }
     public Guid? PersonLegalId { get; set; } 
     public virtual PersonReal PersonReal { get; set; }
     public virtual PersonLegal PersonLegal { get; set; }
    }
```

the real one :

```
 public class PersonReal 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Guid Sex { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

and the legal one has :

```
public class PersonLegal 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Guid? TopManager { get; set; }
        public string NationalCode { get; set; }
    }
```

the person is always one of the real or legal type and not both of the same time .
what is the best pattern to implement person using design pattern?

Comment: Inheritance doesn't do the job?

Comment: I don't think so . they have different properties but they are persons

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them. For example: are they going to be used in a common `List<Person>` for example? Would it be enough (in most cases) for them to have specific `ToString` implementations? Also: Why is `TopManager` a `Guid?` and not a `RealPerson`? If you need to treat them differntly in different algorithms, would it make sense to use double-dispatch-visitor pattern?

Comment: Are those entities in the context of a database / ORM framework?

Comment: ^^ "double-dispatch-visitor" => have a look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/ALWuBx

Answer (score 0):

Define an enum for specify the kind of users

```
public enum PersonTypes{
    Real=0,
    Legal=1,
}
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string NationalCode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public PersonTypes Type { get; set; }

    public string ManagerId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("ManagerId")]
    public virtual Person Manager{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: they has completely different properties

Comment: you could use inheritance,for implement that